# Reverse Proxy Authentication in Internet Explorer

Tags: iis, team-foundation-server, arr

I am using IIS ARR as a reverse proxy for Team Foundation Server 2013.

When I use Firefox and Chrome I get prompted for a password, enter it, and gain access to the correct site.  However, when I use Internet Explorer (v11.0.2), when I enter my domain password it prompts for it again and again until I finally get a "Not Authorized" page.

I have tried with and without SSL offloading but I am not sure what else could be causing this - any ideas?

Comment: Can you try with IE v10? You'd have to look in the IIS logs to see what the actual rejection/reason code is.

Answer (score 0):

In IE add the TFS server as a trusted site. Close IE. Open IE and try to authenticate again. Should work.